# installing IBM Worklight Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded the **IBM Worklight Enterprise Server**, trying to install **Worklight server** with **Apache Tomcat** and deploy my worklight application in my remote server.
It is mentioned in the readme file, that I need "IBM installation Manager" to install the "IBM Worklight Server".
I downloaded the **IBM installation Manager** and followed the steps in the readme file and installed the Worklight server in my local machine. 
Installed **Apache Tomcat** in my remote machine and copied the **worklight- jee-library.jar** to the **$TOMCAT_HOME/lib** directory. 
Is this the right way to install IBM Worklight server ?, or is there any other way to install "IBM Worklight Enterprise Server" in my remote machine from the command line ?
I am stuck at this place
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks 
Suren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not the right way. Specifically, you should not copy anything into Tomcat. The installation does it for you.
The steps to follow are

1. Install the IBM Installation Manager version 1.5.2 and onward (available on the web). This is a one time step.
2. Download the Worklight server package from IBM
3. Point the IBM Installation Manager to the Worklight server package (File - Preferences in main screen).
4. Start the installation.
   The installation will ask you for a path to Tomcat and will install everything that is needed inside Tomcat.

If your server does not have a GUI, the steps 3 and 4 are replaced by the so-called [silent installation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_silent_installation.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response Yaron, I don't have the access to the GUI of my remote server, is there any alternate way to install ?.

Comment: The IBM Installation manager has a silent install mechanism. I am not sure how it works, but I know that it exists.

Comment: Here is the doc for a silent install of Worklight Server https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_silent_installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Quite often you won't have access to the server GUI but you can simply redirect the X display output to your desktop and launch IM. Ie. if you are running Linux export DISPLAY=xxx.xxx.xx:0.0

If you are running Windows just use Exceed.